# DispatchGroup and Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, grand-central-dispatch, background-process

My application uses `Swift` 3.1, `Realm` 2.7.0 as database and has a background service that uses the `DispatchGroup` to control my flow of a determined process.

First things first, in my `ViewController` I did an implementation of the `Realm`'s notification system, knows as `NotificationToken`, that uses the method `addNotificationBlock` to detect any change of data in a determined object.

Until then, everything is ok. This block is invoked on all changes.

I have implemented a new process that uses a bunch of `DispatchQueue` and `DispatchGroup`, here is an example:

*This code is just a sample! Don't do this!*

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

  autoreleasepool {

    //Other stuff...

    let id = 1337
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue(label: "Process").sync {

      let foo = Bar()

      foo.progress = { newValueInt in
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
          realm
            .object(ofType: Some.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
            .someValue = newValueInt
        }
      }

      foo.completed = {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
      }

      foo.doSomethingAsync()

    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
      //Process completed.
    }

  }

}
```

The problem is: The `addNotificationBlock` is not invoked and the Object added on its notification block doesn't update when the method `Bar.progress` runs.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is very simple, you just need to run the update on the main thread.

```
foo.progress = { newValueInt in
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
      let realm = try! Realm()
      try! realm.write {
        realm
          .object(ofType: Some.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
          .someValue = newValueInt
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tell me why. Give me reasons.

Comment: Does Realm has any way to notify all tokenBlocks when the transaction is done? I don't think so.

Comment: Uh, yes it does? Every notification token on UI thread (technically thread with run-loop) is notified if there is a write to Realm on ANY threads?

Comment: `commit()` will not write your data on the `Realm` file, it's just in memory insert (if it is out of the main thread). It is just dispatched when the run-loop, that's why on the main thread it works so well.

Comment: `realm.write(() => {...})` writes to the database in a transaction, commits it (meaning it is written to the Realm file and becomes the "latest version of Realm"), and Realm sends notifications to all threads with a runloop telling them to update their Realm instances, and notify all changed RealmObjects and RealmResults that a change has occurred. If you're doing "in-memory inserts", then you're not actually writing to the Realm... **But you must make sure the Results is not killed by `autoreleasepool` to receive notifications.**

Comment: Well it should by design.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a full app that uses your code, filling in the blanks that you didn't provide, and the notification block is correctly invoked:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Bar {
    var progress: ((Int) -> Void)?
    var completed: (() -> Void)?

    func doSomethingAsync() {
        for delay in 1...100 {
            // Span these 100 updates over 10 seconds
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(delay) / 10) {
                self.progress?(delay)
                if delay == 100 {
                    self.completed?()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init() {}
}

class Some: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var someValue = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

func bgTask() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        autoreleasepool {

            //Other stuff...

            let id = 1337
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            DispatchQueue(label: "Process").sync {
                let foo = Bar()
                foo.progress = { newValueInt in
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    try! realm.write {
                        realm
                            .object(ofType: Some.self, forPrimaryKey: id)!
                            .someValue = newValueInt
                    }
                }
                foo.completed = {
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
                foo.doSomethingAsync()
            }
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .background)) {
                //Process completed.
            }
        }
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var notificationToken: NotificationToken!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let some = Some()
        try! realm.write {
            some.id = 1337
            realm.add(some)
        }
        notificationToken = some.addNotificationBlock { change in
            switch change {
            case .change(let properties):
                print(properties)
            case .error(let error):
                print("An error occurred: \(error)")
            case .deleted:
                print("The object was deleted.")
            }
        }
        bgTask()
        return true
    }
}
```

This logs (truncated for brevity):

```
[RealmSwift.PropertyChange(name: "someValue", oldValue: Optional(0), newValue: Optional(1))]
[RealmSwift.PropertyChange(name: "someValue", oldValue: Optional(1), newValue: Optional(2))]
[RealmSwift.PropertyChange(name: "someValue", oldValue: Optional(2), newValue: Optional(3))]
[RealmSwift.PropertyChange(name: "someValue", oldValue: Optional(3), newValue: Optional(4))]
[RealmSwift.PropertyChange(name: "someValue", oldValue: Optional(4), newValue: Optional(5))]
...
[RealmSwift.PropertyChange(name: "someValue", oldValue: Optional(98), newValue: Optional(97))]
[RealmSwift.PropertyChange(name: "someValue", oldValue: Optional(97), newValue: Optional(100))]
```

Comment: This is not my source code. Just a coincidence. Neither a inspiration. I never touched this code. :)

Comment: There is no reason to see this working, since this code dispatches to the background queue, I was doing this and it only fixed after change to dispatch on the main thread.

Comment: Writes on background thread will notify on UI thread the Realm instance 
 and notification tokens of Results/Object if a change has occurred to them. There is no need to write to Realm on UI thread.

Comment: Sorry jpsim, but this solution doesn't work on my case. Any implementation that doesn't use the main dispatch doesn't reflect in any notification on the `NotificationBlock`.

Comment: `foo.progress` is `AWSS3UploadPartRequest.uploadProgress { bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend }`

Comment: I can only provide an answer based on the information you've provided. If there's more information that's relevant to your problem, you'll need to share that for others to be able to help you.

Comment: No problem. I understand this. :) I couldn't imagine that is a problem with a external component of the AWSS3 library.